# FormJSON PHP para CURL ,

Tags: php, html, json, libcurl

Como passar de ...

> file_get_contents()

para **CURL** ou Guzzle

```
$content = http_build_query(array(
'oid' => '00SH1000000ASZF',
'retURL' => 'https://www.site.com.br/', 
'first_name' => $nome,                                              
'last_name' => $sobrenome,
'cpf__c' => rmCaracter($f['cpf']),
'mobile' => rmCaracter($f['phone']),
'email' => $f['email'],                                             
'type__c' => 'HAB',
'Lead_Source' => 'Website Concessionaria',
'sub_source_media__c' => 'Site',                                  
'dealer_code_interest__c' => '137492',
'opt_in_email__c' => '1',
'opt_in_phone__c' => '1',                                               
'model_interest__c' => $f['model'],
));

$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'method'  => 'POST',
'content' => $content,
)
));                                             

$result = file_get_contents('https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8', null, $context);
```

Estou recebendo um erro em **$result** .::

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead…):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 TLS 1.1 or
>   higher required in
>   /home/storage/9/8e/3d/teste1124/public_html/tpl/site.php on line 124

**Acredito ser a Solução pois, ... Se eu ponho a url desse webservice no action de um form e envio os mesmos dados, não tenho o erro,  mas da forma que montei meu json , sim tenho esse erro ai.**

Meu Form + Json = https://pastebin.com/mvai8JP7

> A maioria dos alojamentos agora bloqueia o parâmetro furl_open que
>   permite usar file_get_contents() para carregar dados de um URL
>   externo. Acho que posso usar CURL ou uma biblioteca de clientes PHP
>   como Guzzle, como solução.

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/256314/edit) sua pergunta e esclareça seu problema, pois da maneira como está não da para entender.

Comment: @Wéllingthon M. de Souza Preciso mudar o meu JSON para CURL  pois ... Acredito ser a Solução pois, ... Se eu ponho a url desse webservice no action de um form e envio os mesmos dados, não tenho o erro, mas da forma que montei meu json , sim tenho esse erro ai.

Comment: @Articuno   Pode ajudar sabe ........  Não estou conseguindo !

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando *cURL* ficaria assim:

```
$content = array(
  'oid' => '00SH1000000ASZF',
  'retURL' => 'https://www.site.com.br/',
  'first_name' => $nome,
  'last_name' => $sobrenome,
  'cpf__c' => rmCaracter($f['cpf']),
  'mobile' => rmCaracter($f['phone']),
  'email' => $f['email'],
  'type__c' => 'HAB',
  'Lead_Source' => 'Website Concessionaria',
  'sub_source_media__c' => 'Site',
  'dealer_code_interest__c' => '137492',
  'opt_in_email__c' => '1',
  'opt_in_phone__c' => '1',
  'model_interest__c' => $f['model'],
);

$context = http_build_query($content);
$url = 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';

// Abre a conexão
$ch = curl_init();

// Seta a URL, método como POST, e os dados a ser enviado
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $context);

// Executa
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

// Fecha a conexão
curl_close($ch);
```

> Obs.: Não foi possível fazer o teste, pois no momento não estou em um computador adequado.

#### Referência

- [cURL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

Comment: o echo $result;  veio =  1   ,  sinal que deu certo  ?

Comment: Se esse é o retorno que o site da quando recebe as informações com sucesso, sim, pois esta retornando `TRUE`, não tem como você verificar no site no qual esta fazendo a requisição se ele recebeu ?

Comment: @Wéllingthon M. de Souza  Não entrou nos leads Não !

Comment: @PauloMaia o que tem em `$nome` ? como você está recebendo o valores dessas variáveis?

Comment: @Wéllingthon M. de Souza Veja =   https://pastebin.com/mvai8JP7

Comment: @Wéllingthon M. de Souza  Não esta recebendo não  !

Comment: Esse link é o mesmo que está na pergunta, como ficou usando o código da resposta? Você pode ver o retorno quando você faz por formulário ? O formulário é submetido via *Ajax* ? Se sim, vai em *Ferramentas do desenvolvedor > Network*

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68918/discussion-between-wmsouza-and-paulomaia).